# how to show points on image in matlab?

Tags: matlab

i have some pixel points lets say p1(1,1) and p2(1,10).......and so on

i want to display these points on image in any color.
how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MATLAB [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) documentation is pretty comprehensive.

[LineSpec](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/linespec.html) properties lists the syntax for different styles of lines, colors, and points.

If you want more options, see [LineSeries Properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/lineseriesproperties.html).
You can specify properties such as `Marker` (style), `MarkerEdgeColor`, `MarkerFaceColor`, and `MarkerSize`.

You can also use [RGB triplets](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/visualize/f0-18164.html#f0-5919) to define color, if you want to deviate from rgbcmykw.

Examples:

Plot a single point (3,4) with an orange five-pointed star marker:

```
p=[3,4];
plot(p(1),p(2),'Marker','p','Color',[.88 .48 0],'MarkerSize',20)
```

Plot an array of points with green 'o' markers:

```
p=round(10*rand(2,10));
plot(p(1,:),p(2,:),'go')
```

**EDIT:** If you've got all your points stored as `p1=[x1,y1]`, `p2=[x2,y2]`, etc., try reorganizing them into a 2xN matrix first. Either re-generate the points, or if you've already got them as single pairs, use

```
p=[p1;p2;p3]'; %# the [;] notation vertically concatenates into Nx2, 
               %# and the ' transposes to a 2xN
plot(p(1,:),p(2,:),'go')
```

Or, if you have a ton of points stored as single pairs, say up to p1000 or so, you *could* use [`eval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eval.html) (*cringe*).

```
p=[]; %# initialize p
for n=1:nPoints %# if you've got 1000 points, nPairs should be 1000
eval(['p(:,n)=p',num2str(n)],''); %#executes p(:,n)=pn' for each nPoint
end
```

Comment: but i want to display all points i-e p1,p2,p3..... on image.this displays one point only :o

Comment: Are you storing individual points as `p1=(x1,y1)`, `p2=(x2,y2)`, etc.? Don't do that. MATLAB is made for working with matrices. Store your points in a 2xN matrix and use the plot array of points option in my answer.

Comment: but this eval is not displaying points on image .what to do now? :(

Comment: @chee: Read my entire answer. The last line before the **EDIT** will plot your points after they're in the correct format. (The format you put them in using eval.)

Answer (score 5):

You can just use plot:

```
plot(p1(1), p1(2), 'ko');  % Small circle point in black.
plot(p1(1), p1(2), 'r.');  % Small dot in red.
```

Comment: Don't forget to `hold on` the image first.

Answer (score 4):

Use image, hold on and plot.

```
base_points = [142.3125,93.4375; 169.4375,176.0625];
image(fixed); colormap(gray(256)); axis image;
hold on;
plot(base_points(:,1),base_points(:,2),'go');
```