# Matlab transparent overlay matrix

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, transparent

I want to load an image and then create a `Matrix` with the size of the image.
The Matrix should be transparent with only some spare values (points).
I then want to show the image in a figure and put the Matrix on top.

The code so far:

```
world = imread('map1.jpg');           % import image of location
[x_world,y_world] = size(world);      % get the size of the image
A = zeros(x_world,y_world);           % create matrix with dimension of image

imshow(world);                        % display image
axis image;                           % label the axis
```

My Matrix contains some points:

```
A(200,300) = 1;
A(500,500) = 5;
A(580,200) = 3;
```

if I now iterate through each value in the Matrix like that:

```
for i = 1:x_world
    for j = 1:y_world
        if(A(i,j) == 1)
            plot(i,j,'r.','MarkerSize',20);   % plot a single point
        elseif(A(i,j) == 2)
            plot(i,j,'y.','MarkerSize',20);   % plot a single point
        elseif(A(i,j) == 3)
            plot(i,j,'m.','MarkerSize',20);   % plot a single point
        elseif(A(i,j) == 4)
            plot(i,j,'g.','MarkerSize',20);   % plot a single point
        elseif(A(i,j) == 5)
            plot(i,j,'b.','MarkerSize',20);   % plot a single point
        elseif(A(i,j) == 6)
            plot(i,j,'w.','MarkerSize',20);   % plot a single point
        end
    end
end
```

it would be really slow.

So what I want to do is create a transparent Matrix and then set some points, so that I just can print the Matrix over the original image.

Is that possible? How do I do that? Is there maybe another better way to do that?

Comment: Closely related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842195/how-to-show-points-on-image-in-matlab

Comment: Have a look at ``gscatter()``

Comment: I think this guy shows how to do this: [Image overlay using transparency](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2009/02/18/image-overlay-using-transparency/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a start, you could avoid looping over all of theese rows and columns by actually looping over your 6 groups. The code blow should give the same result:

```
markers = {'r.', 'y.', 'm.', 'g.', 'b.', 'w.'}; % // define some markers
figure
hold on
for group = 1:6
    [i, j] = ind2sub(size(A), find(A==group)); % // find indices of current group
    plot(i, j, markers{group}, 'markersize', 20) % // plot them with their marker
end
```

If speed is an issue, you maybe can have a look at `gscatter()` and or `sparse()`.